# Stop propagation of a specific event inside another event listener

Tags: javascript, dom-events, event-listener, stoppropagation

I have a listener attached to resize event on `window` object. Deeper in my code, I have some `input` fields.

To avoid some issues on android devices, I’d like to **prevent resize listeners from being fired** when an input field is focused (android device resize browser window when opening keyboard, unlike IOS).

*main.js*

```
window.addEventListener(‘resize’, () => {
  // Some stuff here
});
```

*someFile.js*

```
field.addEventListener(‘input’, () => {
  // Here I want to disable the resize event only once
});
```

I came accross the following solutions, without any success so far :

**removeEventListener()**

Not suitable at all, since I need to specify a reference to the listener function. Not only do I have to remove listeners one by one, I also have to list them all, and rebind them after.

**event.stopPropagation()**

*someFile.js*

```
field.addEventListener(‘focusin’, () => {
  window.addEventListener(‘resize’, event => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    // also tried event.stopImmediatePropagation()
  });
});
```

But since listeners are called in declared order, it doesn’t prevent anything (it is declared last). Plus I have to rebind everything again on `focusout`.

**What I want**

I’m aware of some tricks using global variables that can achieve what I want, but they are kinda ugly, not to mention I try to **avoid global variables as much as I can**.

Is there any elegant way, to **invoke an early `stopPropagation()` like function** on all resize listeners, and prevent them from firing from deep function inside code ?

Or is there a **better architecture**, for example a global function that can trigger when any input element on the page gets focus, and prevent the resize event regardless of the focused element ?

Comment: Why not take a flag, and inside your resize check if flag is on or off. If it is on the do not run the code inside of resize. When someone has focussed on field turn the flag to on.

Comment: You may want to look at event delegation (one event listener for all or most events).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd add a `resize` listener *unconditionally*, and inside it, check if `document.activeElement` is one of the fields:

```js
window.addEventListener(
  'resize',
  (e) => {
    if (document.activeElement && document.activeElement.matches('input')) {
      console.log('propagation stopped');
      e.stopPropagation();
    } else {
      console.log('propagation not stopped');
    }
  },
  true // enable useCapture here with this third argument
       // to stop propagation as early as possible
);
```

```html
<input>
```

Change the selector string passed to `matches` to match your needs. The above snippet uses `input`, which will match any input field. If you only want to stop propagation when the focused input has a class of `foo`, you'd use

```
.matches('input.foo')
```

To match multiple selectors, separate them with a comma, eg

```
.matches('input, textarea')
```

will match both an input and a textarea.

Also keep in mind that Javascript syntax requires straight quotes, not so-called smart quotes, which will cause syntax errors.

Comment: Solved, but for me, `stopPropagation()` didn’t worked. I had to use `stopImmediatePropagation()` instead. Thanks !